# Jquery datepicker is behind div

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I have used this datepicker for quite awhile in this specific code.
I made some HTML changes and AJAX calls, and now when im clicking on the input field i dont see the datepicker. seems like it added it to the DOM, if I use Firebug i can see its in the right place but it is not visible (like something is overlaying). but I dont have z-indexes or whatsoerver.

```
    <input type="text" id="inputfield" />
<script type="text/javascript">        $("#inputfield").datepicker({minDate: +1});</script>
```

I have noticed only today about this issue. they disappeared. maybe google changed the Jquery repository files or something?

I am using jquery 1.4.2 & ui 1.8.2
What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a link to the site?

Comment: Can you show us a working demo?

Comment: As others have asked, please post your code. Also, tell us which specific date picker you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Google must have modified the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

so I am now using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This might be because use of ajax.